Simplified Kaya equation - Can carbon emissions over the next 25 years be seen as the product of population growth, GDP/Person growth, and CO2/GDP?
This simplified Kaya equation is a powerful tool to raise awareness about how carbon emissions can be seen as the product of 3 factors :

the population growth
the GPD/person growth
the spread between GDP growth and carbon reduction.

In our model, that you can test on https://kayaquiz.com we essentially ask the user to guess where population will be in 2050, where the GDP per person will be, and how fast we can decarbonate. Then calculate the resulting amount of carbon produced between today and 2050, and deduct on what IPCC scenario we stand.
We're mesmerized by the idea and the model, and believe it has solid merits and works mathematically, but we're not economists or mathematicians.
As we want to syndicate the tool to wider audiences and be ready to receive critics and argue in a constructive way (or recognize major flaws in the tool) we are looking for critics or confirmations on those merits, or flaws.
One that has been mentioned a few times in the first few 1000s uses is the linearity. There might be other issues.
Appreciate your time and views on the subject.
Happy to explain more how we do the calculation as well, it is by no means rocket science.
